# MVC 3 Webgrid make entire row clickable

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor, webgrid

I am using webgrid in my razor view in MVC 3.
Below is how my webGrid looks, I want to make the entire row clickable and on click pass values to the javascript method also.

I am able to achieve calling my javascript method on text of all columns. I want the same to happen for click of anywhere on the entire row.

Please guide me on this. Thanks

```
           @grid.GetHtml(

            columns: grid.Columns(

            grid.Column("CompanyName", format: @<text><a href="javascript:SubmitValues('@item.Col1','@item.Col2','@item.Col3');">@item.CompanyName</a></text>, header: "ABC"),

            grid.Column("CompanyAddress", format: @<text><a href="javascript:SubmitValues('@item.Col1','@item.Col2','@item.Col3');">@item.CompanyName</a></text>, header: "DEF"),

            ))      

         }
```

Comment: LoL ! was awarded TumbleWeed for this : Asked a question with no votes, no answers, no comments, and low views for a week. Hope now answers will start pouring in ! :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use JQuery to add row click functionality

Add htmlAttributes: new { id="MainTable" } in your webgrid.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(function () {
        var tr = $('#MainTable').find('tr');
        tr.bind('click', function (event) {
            var values = '';
            var tds = $(this).find('td');


            $.each(tds, function (index, item) {
                values = values + 'td' + (index + 1) + ':' + item.innerHTML + '<br/>';
            });
            alert(values);


        });
    }); 


</script>
```

Comment: and how do I pass values '@item.Col1','@item.Col2','@item.Col' to my javascript function ?

Comment: You are already passing the parameter. The above code will only highlight the row. Rest your code will do

Answer (score 2):

I have done this in my project with adding a class `style: "click_able"` on specific column like.

```
grid.Column("CompanyName", style: "click_able", format: @<text><a href="javascript:SubmitValues('@item.Col1','@item.Col2','@item.Col3');">@item.CompanyName</a></text>, header: "ABC"),
```

and then add click function like.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(".click_able").click(function () {
    // Do something 
});
```

It working fine in my case.