# MVC WebGrid, row select

Tags: asp.net-mvc, row, webgrid

I have simple WebGrid with item:

```
  grid.Column(format: (item) => @Ajax.ActionLink("Select", "LoadForEdit", "Receipt", new { Id = Model.Services.IndexOf(@item.Value) }, new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "ItemToEdit" }))
```

And i want to select when actually clicking on row, not only on 'select' item  in that row.
Is it possible?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MVC 3 Webgrid make entire row clickable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10445690/mvc-3-webgrid-make-entire-row-clickable)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote an article on making WebGrid rows "clickable" for Razor Web Pages (http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/178/How-To-Make-A-WebGrid-Row-Clickable) using jQuery. You can adapt the code to MVC very easily.

Comment: A year on, has anybody posted an MVC adaptation of your article?

Comment: @CodeswithHammer All you have to do is move the code that generates the data to the controller and pass in a model to the WebGrid contructor. The creation of the grid and the jQuery stay in the View.